# How can I shorten this function using a FirstOrDefault and Lambda expression?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a method in Unity that loops through a set of `GameObject`s to see which of them has a bool `isClosestLadder` set to `true`.

If one of them has that bool set to `true`, it returns the position of that object.

```c#
public Vector3 FindNearestLadder()
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>().Length; i++)
    {
        if (transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Ladder>().isClosestLadder)
        {
           return transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Ladder>().transform.position;
        }
    }
    return Vector3.zero;
}
```

Can anyone show me how I can shorten this function using a FirstOrDefault and Lambda expression?

Comment: I'm a little concerned that you seem to have a method on the Ladder class `isClosestLadder` - meaning that check is being run for as many ladders that you have in your scene. Assuming there's one player, you're much better off running that check on the player object, rather than the ladder

Comment: It's just an OntriggerEnter2d method inside the ladder class that sets the member bool isClosestLadder to true.

Comment: I suggest you to use the current code and forget about lambda. It is faster than what you are trying to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, what you're trying to do can be improved in one way or another, but to answer your question directly, you can use the following.

```
Vector3 FindNearestLadder()
{
    try
    {
        return GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>().Where(x => x.isClosestLadder== true).FirstOrDefault().transform.position;
    }
    catch
    {
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Edit:

As Draco has pointed out, this will require adding a using statement `using System.Linq` to the top of the class. I would've thought this was obvious, given your choice to use FirstOrDefault and Lambda, as this is only really common while using Linq, in my experience.

Comment: This won't work. `GetComponentsInChildren` returns a typed array, not a List<>, and as such, does not have the `.Where` method from Generics.

Comment: ...Only if you include `using System.Linq;` which is not included by default when creating a new Unity script and you didn't mention it in your answer. Where as a List<> from `System.Generics` supports Predicates by default, which is included in the default imports. A straight copy-paste gives "error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Ladder[]' does not contain a definition for `Where' and no extension method `Where' of type `UnityEngine.Ladder[]' could be found."

Comment: @Draco18s Of course combinations of FirstOrDefault and Lambda are going to require `using System.Linq` - as any competent programmer would know. In case it wasn't clear enough, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: The predicates in System.Generic are *also* Lambda functions and don't require importing System.Linq, so the "of course" is not accurate. But thanks for editing that into your answer.

Comment: Thanks Bejasc, I already had using System.Linq in my code, but what do you think of the  3 examples that Draco18s gave in his response?

Comment: Our answers are very similar, though as Draco suggest, his is likely more performant. However in this case, unless you have thousands of ladders, any performance hit would be pretty neglible I'd imagine, so it would essentially be on your preference for which reads better and cleaner to you (which is typically my goal when I use linq)

Answer (score 0):

Eugh. Not caching the result of `GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>()` is doing more damage than the fact that your function is five lines long.

Seriously, you should have done this:

```c#
public Vector3 FindNearestLadder() { 
    Ladder[] ladders = GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>();    
    for (int i = 0; i < ladders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ladders[i].isClosestLadder)
        {
           return ladders[i].transform.position;
        }
    }
    return Vector3.zero;
}
```

Look at how many fewer lookup calls (get transform child by index, get component...) that is.

But if you really want to lambdaize this...

```c#
public Vector3 FindNearestLadder() {
    Ladder[] allComp = GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>();
    List<Ladder> allCompList = new List<Ladder>(allComp);
    return allCompList.Find(x => x.isClosestLadder).transform.position;
}
```

Or if you are really concerned by line count...

```c#
public Vector3 FindNearestLadder() {
    Ladder[] allComp = GetComponentsInChildren<Ladder>();
    return new List<Ladder>(allComp).Find(x => x.isClosestLadder).transform.position;
}
```

Comment: @Programmer Me either, and it was within minutes of my posting it.

Comment: Thanks Draco18s. I should definitely have cached those lookup calls. Which of those 3 functions would you use in your code? I’m not familiar with linq and lambda. All I know is that they can shorten my code. Are they slower than just using the first example you gave?

Comment: @CareyOn It depends, but I'd use the second most likely. The inlining of the List<> doesn't feel right to me, but if there was a chance that there might not be a match, I would likely use the first (or restructure the second to use more lines to allow for a null check--I was overly ambitious in golfing the method). A `FindAll().ForEach()` might also work. Or returning the component that matches and doing the null check where the method is used...As for performance, they'd be largely equivalent. If not exactly so.